# Emacs elisp configuration file doesn't recognize default-directory

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have my emacs configuration file under `~/.emacs` with just one declaration:

`(setq default-directory "/var/www/")`

What I want to do is to `C-x C-f` and go directly to my apache directory. But I tried using `C-x C-f` and my current directory is `HOME`.

The file gets loaded, because I used this: `(shell)` and the shell gets opened. Anyone knows where my error is? I just want to set the start-up directory in htdocs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, it was a really weird problem.

Every time I try to open a file from the default buffer (`*GNU Emacs*`) it changes the default directory to `~/`, but when I try to open a file from another buffer, it opens to the one I specified in my variable.

Answer (score 3):

`default-directory` does not do what you seem to think. <kbd>C-h v</kbd>
<kbd>default-directory</kbd>

```
default-directory is a variable defined in `buffer.c'.
Its value is "/"
Local in buffer stackoverflow.com/questions/14914353; global value is nil

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set in any fashion.
  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate `stringp'.

Documentation:
Name of default directory of current buffer.  Should end with slash.
To interactively change the default directory, use command `cd'.
```

It's a buffer-local (i.e. buffer specific) variable, meaning its value is
different depending on which buffer is currently active.  So when you think you've set it to
"/var/www", you are simply visiting a file already in that directory.

If you want to open a file from "/var/www", you need to make your own command
that binds "/var/www" to `default-directory`.

Comment: Unrelated question: Do you browse stackoverflow from Emacs? Is there a mode for that? Which one please?

Comment: No, I edit my answers in Emacs using a chrome "Edit With Emacs" plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is wondering how to do this:

As @Pacha was saying, when emacs starts, the welcome screen shows up and it will change your working directory to the `command-line-default-directory`

So, for example, If you want your default directory to be "~/", add this to your .emacs and you should be on track.

```
(setq command-line-default-directory "~/")
(setq default-directory "~/")
```